# Fetching mysqli data and security

Tags: mysqli

I am using prepared statements to enter data into the database, but I am not using prepared statements to fetch data.  The reason is that the code is a little smaller and from what I read, its a little faster.  Are there any security issues with this?

Example:

to insert data;

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT USERS (userFname) ( VALUES (?)");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', $userFname); 
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt); 
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
```

to fetch data;

```
$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE userEmail = '$userEmail'");
```

is this method as safe as using prepared statements to fetch data?

Comment: You should **always** use prepared statements. No exceptions.

Comment: I will change my code, Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

In  your example, lets say there's a form login

```
<input type="email" name="email"><button type="submit">login</button>
```

your php script runs:

```
<?php
$email = $_POST['email'];
$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE userEmail = '$email'");
```

so, here is an attack vector where someone can do "fun stuff" with your database.

Now, if your script NEVER comes in contact with a user input, and it only runs in a loop by fetching emails from a record, then fetching the corresonding user you might think you're safe.
But how safe is that source you have there?

You have a table `newsletter_signups`

```
id| email                                      | registered
1 | billy_joe@outlook.com                      | 2017-04-02
2 | johnny@tables.com');Drop table `users`;--  | 2017-05-01
```

and you start looping through it.

```
foreach($newsletter_records as $record) {
    $email = $record['email'];
    $query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE userEmail = '$email'");
    ... etc...
}
```

You can imagine the pain that'll cause.

In short. You can never, ever, ever trust data to be safe.
Be paranoid concerning data and always use prepared statements. It should be your default way to go. even if it's 100% safe.
Added benefit is, you can usually reuse the prepared statement and just swap out the variables, making your code run faster.